# Changing label to allow multiline doubles width of View in interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I'm having a bit of a weird problem in interface builder:

When I switch the label lines from `1` to `0`, in order to allow a multi-line label, the width of the view in interface builder is doubled. I have constraints for the label to the stack view it in, and the highest stack view has constraints to the safe area. I tried changing the highest constraints to superview, but it didn't change anything.

When the app is running, the view behaves as it should. However, its a pain to work on it when it looks like this:

**Lines set to 1:**
[image: Lines set to 1]

**Lines set to 0:**
[image: Lines set to 0]

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution to this is setting width of that label `Greater Than or Equal to 300` (a width which looks ok in storyboard)

Comment: This works. However I'd love to implement a more dynamic solution

Comment: width will be dynamic in this case, it will grow if text is more. you just need minimum width of label so that stack is drawn correctly by storyboard.